# Can each of axis2 web services have own log file using log4j?

Tags: web-services, log4j, apache-axis, logging

Is it possible to achive each of axis2 web services have own log file using log4j?
For example i want my authentication service have auth.log and pool service have pool.log file.

Best regards,
Bojan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem with that. Just use differently named loggers in each web service implementation and configure a separate `FileAppender` for each of them. Here's a minimum configuration example that can give you an idea how to do it:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="fileAppender1" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
   <param name="file" value="webservice1.log"/>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppender2" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
   <param name="file" value="webservice2.log"/>
</appender>

<logger name="org.x.logger1">
   <appender ref="fileAppender1"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.x.logger2">
   <appender ref="fileAppender2"/>
</logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: @snijele Great. BTW, the `debug="true"` was not needed, removed it.

Comment: Where exactly (in which configuration file) do you put these statements? What is the default log file for Axis2?

Comment: @PNS This is a fragment of `log4j.xml` file. Axis2 logs via Apache Commons Logging, which is an API you need to configure to use with most logging libraries, log4j included; see http://commons.apache.org/logging/.